# Visual Studio: Automatic (Re-)Generation of Solution Folders

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I've recently found it very convenient to organize the many projects in my Unity game solution into "solution folders", which exist only in Visual Studio (not in the file system); if I do this, ReSharper can very neatly organize the project dependency graph for me.  (It's getting very large, because ... reasons.)

The problem is, these folders get wiped out every time Unity rebuilds the project *.csproj files.  I've tried playing with the file generation hook as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/customize-project-files-created-by-vstu?view=vs-2019), but haven't had any luck -- I'm not sure the property I'm looking for is even settable from the csproj XML.

So: Is there any way to either save the solution folders, or automatically re-create them when csproj files get refreshed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd given up on solving this problem, but 6 weeks later I stumbled across the solution.  For anyone with the same concern: You must install the "Visual Studio Editor" package within Unity.  [As of this summer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ide.visualstudio@2.0/changelog/CHANGELOG.html?_ga=2.59783086.2070808663.1600715668-1522554364.1510261404#202---2020-05-27), this package supports solution folders in VS!